# Why does 2 == [2] in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties

I recently discovered that `2 == [2]` in JavaScript.  As it turns out, this quirk has a couple of interesting consequences:

```
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3];
a[[2]] === a[2]; // this is true
```

Similarly, the following works:

```
var a = { "abc" : 1 };
a[["abc"]] === a["abc"]; // this is also true
```

Even stranger still, this works as well:

```
[[[[[[[2]]]]]]] == 2; // this is true too! WTF?
```

These behaviors seem consistent across all browsers.

Any idea why this is a language feature?

Here are more insane consequences of this "feature":

```
[0] == false // true
if ([0]) { /* executes */ } // [0] is both true and false!

var a = [0];
a == a // true
a == !a // also true, WTF?
```

Comment: So you discovered that idempotent operations turn out the same output not only when applied just once, but even more.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You can look up the comparison algorithm in the ECMA-spec (relevant sections of ECMA-262, 3rd edition for your problem: 11.9.3, 9.1, 8.6.2.6).

If you translate the involved abstract algorithms back to JS, what happens when evaluating `2 == [2]` is basically this:

```
2 === Number([2].valueOf().toString())
```

where `valueOf()` for arrays returns the array itself and the string-representation of a one-element array is the string representation of the single element.

This also explains the third example as `[[[[[[[2]]]]]]].toString()` is still just the string `2`.

As you can see, there's quite a lot of behind-the-scene magic involved, which is why I generally only use the strict equality operator `===`.

The first and second example are easier to follow as property names are always strings, so

```
a[[2]]
```

is equivalent to

```
a[[2].toString()]
```

which is just

```
a["2"]
```

Keep in mind that even numeric keys are treated as property names (ie strings) before any array-magic happens.

Answer (score 10):

It is because of the implicit type conversion of `==` operator.

[2] is converted to Number is 2 when compared with a Number. Try the unary `+` operator on [2].

```
> +[2]
2
```

Comment: Others are saying [2] is converted to a string. `+"2"` is also the number 2.

Comment: Actually, it's not that easy. [2] is converted to string would be closer but have a look at http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Answer (score 10):

```
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3];
a[[2]] === a[2]; // this is true
```

On the right side of the equation, we have the a[2], which returns a number type with value 2. On the left, we are first creating a new array with a single object of 2. Then we are calling a[(array is in here)]. I am not sure if this evaluates to a string or a number. 2, or "2". Lets take the string case first. I believe a["2"] would create a new variable and return null. null !== 2. So lets assume it is actually implicitly converting to a number. a[2] would return 2. 2 and 2 match in type (so === works) and value. I think it is implicitly converting the array to a number because a[value] expects a string or number. It looks like number takes higher precedence.

On a side note, I wonder who determines that precedence. Is because [2] has a number as it's first item, so it converts to a number? Or is it that when passing an array into a[array] it tries to turn the array into a number first, then string. Who knows?

```
var a = { "abc" : 1 };
a[["abc"]] === a["abc"];
```

In this example, you are creating an object called a with a member called abc. The right side of the equation is pretty simple; it is equivalent to a.abc. This returns 1. The left side first creates a literal array of ["abc"]. You then search for a variable on the a object by passing in the newly created array. Since this expects a string, it converts the array into a string. This now evaluates to a["abc"], which equals 1. 1 and 1 are the same type (which is why === works) and equal value.

```
[[[[[[[2]]]]]]] == 2;
```

This is just an implicit conversion. === wouldn't work in this situation because there is a type mismatch.

Comment: The answer to your question about precedence: `==` applies `ToPrimitive()` to the array, which in turn invokes its `toString()` method, so what you actually compare is the number `2` to the string `"2"`; comparison between a string and a number is done by converting the string

Answer (score 8):

For the `==` case, this is why [Doug Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/) recommends always using `===`.  It doesn't do any implicit type conversion.

For the examples with `===`, the implicit type conversion is done before the equality operator is called.

Answer (score 8):

```
[0] == false // true
if ([0]) { /* executes */ } // [0] is both true and false!
```

That's interesting, it's not that [0] is both true and false, actually

```
[0] == true // false
```

It is javascript's funny way of processing if() operator.

Comment: actually, it's the funny way `==` works; if you use an actual explicit cast (ie `Boolean([0])` or `!![0]`), you'll find that `[0]` will evaluate to `true` in boolean contexts as it should: in JS, any object is considered `true`

Answer (score 7):

A array of one item can be treated as the item itself.

This is due to duck typing. Since "2" == 2 == [2] and possibly more.

Comment: because they dont match in type. in the first example, the left side is evaluated first, and they wind up matching in type.

Comment: Also, I don't think duck-typing is the correct word here. It is more to do with the implicit type conversion performed by `==` operator before comparing.

Comment: this has nothing to do with duck typing but rather with weak typing, ie implicit type conversion

Comment: What Chetan and Christoph said.

Answer (score 3):

To add a little detail to the other answers... when comparing an `Array` to a `Number`, Javascript will convert the `Array` with `parseFloat(array)`. You can try it yourself in the console (eg Firebug or Web Inspector) to see what different `Array` values get converted to.

```
parseFloat([2]); // 2
parseFloat([2, 3]); // 2
parseFloat(['', 2]); // NaN
```

For `Array`s, `parseFloat` performs the operation on the `Array`'s first member, and discards the rest.

Edit: Per Christoph's details, it may be that it is using the longer form internally, but the results are consistently identical to `parseFloat`, so you can always use `parseFloat(array)` as shorthand to know for sure how it will be converted.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing 2 objects in every case.. Dont use ==, if you are thinking of comparison, you are having === in mind and not ==. == can often give insane effects. Look for the good parts in the language :)

Answer (score 1):

Explanation for the **EDIT** section of the question:

**1st Example**

```
[0] == false // true
if ([0]) { /* executes */ } // [0] is both true and false!
```

First typecast [0] to a primitive value as per Christoph's answer above we have "0" (`[0].valueOf().toString()`)

```
"0" == false
```

Now, typecast Boolean(false) to Number and then String("0") to Number

```
Number("0") == Number(false)
or  0 == 0 
so, [0] == false  // true
```

As for `if` statement, if there is not an explicit comparison in the if condition itself, the condition evaluates for **truthy** values.

There are only **6 falsy values**: false, null, undefined, 0, NaN and empty string "". And anything that is not a falsy value is a truthy value.

Since [0] is not a falsy value, it is a truthy value, the `if` statement evaluates to true & executes the statement.

---

**2nd Example**

```
var a = [0];
a == a // true
a == !a // also true, WTF?
```

Again type casting the values to primitive,

```
    a = a
or  [0].valueOf().toString() == [0].valueOf().toString()
or  "0" == "0" // true; same type, same value


a == !a
or  [0].valueOf().toString() == [0].valueOf().toString()
or  "0" == !"0"
or  "0" == false
or  Number("0") == Number(false)
or  0 = 0   // true
```