# Passing a variable to an if statement in a function

Tags: javascript, comparison

Here is what I'm trying to do, I want to pass a variable to a function (no problems there). But then I want to use it in an if statement.

```
colnum(5, 1);


    function colnum (columnnumber, reset)
    {
        var divcount = $('[class^="box"]').length;  
        var columnnumberround = Math.round(divcount / columnnumber);
        var start = 0;
        var end = columnnumberround-1;  

        if (reset=1)
        {
            var i = 0;
            while (i<=columnnumber)
            {
              $('div.box'+start).add($("div.box"+start).nextUntil("div.box"+end)).add($("div.box"+end)).addClass("col"+i);
              $(".col"+i).wrapAll("<div class=column></div>");

              start+=columnnumberround;
              end+=columnnumberround;
              i++;
            }       
        }
        else
        {
            alert("test");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It should be "if (reset == 1) " a.s.o.

Comment: and why are you overwriting the input arg? `var columnnumber = 5;`

Comment: woops, thats something that remained from a testing thing

Answer (score 2):

It should *actually* be:

```
if (reset === 1)
```

JavaScript has two different equality operators, `==` and `===`.
See [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Using the type-coercing equality operator (`==`) can lead to WTFs like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724255/why-does-2-2-in-javascript):

```
> [[[[[[[2]]]]]]] == 2
  true
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are using '=' instead of '==' in your IF statements

```
if (reset=1)
```

should be

```
if (reset==1)
```