# Why is [1,2] + [3,4] = "1,23,4" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, concatenation

I wanted to add the elements of an array into another, so I tried this:

```
[1,2] + [3,4]
```

It responded with:

```
"1,23,4"
```

What is going on?

Comment: Here's a question related to this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724255/why-does-2-2-in-javascript

Comment: Ah-ha-ha, sadist interviewer can ask even something like - what this will return [1,2] + [5,6,7][1,2]. why?

Comment: I think [1,2] + [3,4] has been the most evaluated expression in firebug this week, after alert('crap').

Comment: Wanna laugh ? Try [] + [], {} + [], {} + {}, and [] + {}

Comment: @shabunc - care to explain why `[5,6,7][1,2]` is `7` because it uses the last item in the second array. O.o

Comment: @vsync - I'm very bad with "care to explain" construction, since I'm not native speaker? So, you are basicall asking why? Becase well, list ot comma separated values resolves to last one in "take index" context.

Comment: @shabunc - so weird. I wish there was a video of the meeting when "they" had decided on all those weird things. I really would like to watch how they had got to be.

Comment: @vsync I'm guessing that's not the full picture. Compare the nearly-identical `[1,2]+[5,6][1,2]`, which apparently evaluates to `"1,2undefined"`! JavaScript is inhumane. Why are we so collectively committed to perpetrating this pain? 

Answer (score 530, accepted):

The `+` operator **is not defined for arrays**.

What happens is that Javascript **converts arrays into strings** and concatenates those.

### Update

Since this question and consequently my answer is getting a lot of attention I felt it would be useful and relevant to have an **overview** about how the `+` operator behaves in general also.

So, here it goes.

Excluding E4X and implementation-specific stuff, Javascript (as of ES5) has **6** built-in [data types](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-typeof-operator):

1. Undefined
2. Null
3. Boolean
4. Number
5. String
6. Object

Note that although `typeof` [somewhat confusingly returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Javascript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof) `object` for Null and `function` for callable Objects, Null is actually not an Object and strictly speaking, in specification-conforming Javascript implementations all functions are considered to be Objects.

That's right - Javascript has **no primitive arrays** as such; only instances of an Object called `Array` with some syntactic sugar to ease the pain.

Adding more to the confusion, wrapper entities such as `new Number(5)`, `new Boolean(true)` and `new String("abc")` are all of `object` type, not numbers, booleans or strings as one might expect. Nevertheless for arithmetic operators `Number` and `Boolean` behave as numbers.

Easy, huh? With all that out of the way, we can move on to the overview itself.

**Different result types of `+` by operand types**

```
            || undefined | null   | boolean | number | string | object |
=========================================================================
 undefined  || number    | number | number  | number | string | string | 
 null       || number    | number | number  | number | string | string | 
 boolean    || number    | number | number  | number | string | string | 
 number     || number    | number | number  | number | string | string | 
 string     || string    | string | string  | string | string | string | 
 object     || string    | string | string  | string | string | string |
```

<sup>* applies to Chrome13, FF6, Opera11 and IE9. Checking other browsers and versions is left as an exercise for the reader.</sup>

**Note:** As pointed out by [CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445/cms), for certain cases of objects such as `Number`, `Boolean` and custom ones the `+` operator doesn't necessarily produce a string result. It can vary depending on the implementation of object to primitive conversion. For example `var o = { valueOf:function () { return 4; } };` evaluating `o + 2;` produces `6`, a `number`, evaluating `o + '2'` produces `'42'`, a `string`.

To see how the overview table was generated visit http://jsfiddle.net/1obxuc7m/

Comment: What if you add up two `Date` objects? `typeof new Date()` returns `"object"`. According to your table the result of the addition should be a string, but that's not the case. It's a number. There has to be more to the addition operator than what the table displays. It's not valid in every case.

Comment: @user15321167 Open developer console, write `typeof(new Date() + new Date())` and press enter. The result will be `string` unless you're using a browser that runs a non-standard javascript implementation. The table is valid.

Answer (score 248):

JavaScript's `+` operator has two purposes: adding two numbers, or joining two strings. It doesn't have a specific behaviour for arrays, so it's converting them to strings and then joining them.

If you want to join two arrays to produce a new one, use [the `.concat` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead:

```
[1, 2].concat([3, 4]) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you want to efficiently add all elements from one array to another, you need to use [the .push method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
var data = [1, 2];

// ES6+:
data.push(...[3, 4]);
// or legacy:
Array.prototype.push.apply(data, [3, 4]);

// data is now [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The behaviour of the `+` operator is defined in [ECMA-262 5e Section 11.6.1](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_11.htm#Section_11.6.1):

> #### 11.6.1   The Addition operator ( + )
>
> The addition operator either performs string concatenation or numeric addition. The production `AdditiveExpression : AdditiveExpression + MultiplicativeExpression` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let `lref` be the result of evaluating `AdditiveExpression`.
> 2. Let `lval` be `GetValue(lref)`.
> 3. Let `rref` be the result of evaluating `MultiplicativeExpression`.
> 4. Let `rval` be `GetValue(rref)`.
> 5. Let `lprim` be `ToPrimitive(lval)`.
> 6. Let `rprim` be `ToPrimitive(rval)`.
> 7. If `Type(lprim)` is `String` or `Type(rprim)` is `String`, then
>
>    1. Return the String that is the result of concatenating `ToString(lprim)` followed by `ToString(rprim)`
> 8. Return the result of applying the addition operation to `ToNumber(lprim)` and `ToNumber(rprim)`. See the Note below 11.6.3.

You can see that each operand is converted `ToPrimitive`. By reading further we can find that `ToPrimitive` will always convert arrays to strings, producing this result.

Comment: +1 as this answer not only explains the problem, but also explains how to do it right.

Comment: there's a little tmi here, but I agree with schnaader. The best answers explain the problem/error/behavior that's being asked about then shows how to produce the intended result. +1

Comment: Why would you use the more verbose `Array.prototype.push.apply(data, [3, 4])` instead of `data.concat([3,4])`?

Comment: @evilcelery: They serve different purposes. `concat` produces a *new* Array, the longer call efficiently extends an *existing* Array.

Comment: You can use `[].push.apply(data, [3,4])` for slightly less verbosity.  Also, that is guaranteed to be resistant to other people changing the value of `Array`.

Answer (score 43):

It adds the two **arrays** as if they were **strings**.

The string representation for the first array would be **"1,2"** and the second would be **"3,4"**. So when the `+` sign is found, it cannot sum arrays and then concatenate them as being strings.

Comment: Yes, that is the first and unique explanation comming to the mind but, isn't that a very weird behaviour? maybe there's some dark, unknow operation / transformation being done, and I would love to know the inners :P

Answer (score 40):

The `+` concats strings, so it converts the arrays to strings.

```
[1,2] + [3,4]
'1,2' + '3,4'
1,23,4
```

To combine arrays, use `concat`.

```
[1,2].concat([3,4])
[1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 21):

In JavaScript, the binary addition operator (`+`) performs both numerical addition and string concatenation.  However, when it's first argument is neither a number nor a string then it converts it into a string (hence "`1,2`") then it does the same with the second "`3,4`" and concatenates them to "`1,23,4`".

Try using the "concat" method of Arrays instead:

```js
var a = [1, 2];
var b = [3, 4];
a.concat(b) ; // => [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

Answer (score 19):

It's converting the individual arrays to strings, then combining the strings.

Answer (score 14):

It looks like JavaScript is turning your arrays into strings and joining them together. If you want to add tuples together, you'll have to use a loop or a map function.

Answer (score 14):

`[1,2]+[3,4]` in JavaScript is same as evaluating:

```
new Array( [1,2] ).toString() + new Array( [3,4] ).toString();
```

and so to solve your problem, best thing would be to add two arrays in-place or without creating a new array:

```
var a=[1,2];
var b=[3,4];
a.push.apply(a, b);
```

Answer (score 12):

It's doing exactly what you asked it to do.

What you're adding together are array references (which JS converts to strings), not numbers as it seems. It's a bit like adding strings together: `"hello " + "world"` = `"hello world"`

Comment: hehe, it ALWAYS does what I asked. The problem is to ask the good question. What intrigues me is the toString() interpretation of the arrays when you add them.

Answer (score 8):

It is because, + operator assumes that the operands are string, if they are not numbers. So, it first converts them to string and concats to give the final result , if its not a number. Also, it does not support arrays.

Comment: The + operator can NOT assume the operands are strings, because 1 + 1 == 2, among others. It's because '+' is not defined for arrays, so it toString-s them.

Answer (score 8):

would be nice if you could overload operators in JavaScript but you can't:
[Can I define custom operator overloads in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700085/can-i-define-custom-operator-overloads-in-javascript)
you can only hack the "==" operator which converts to strings before comparing:
http://blogger.xs4all.nl/peterned/archive/2009/04/01/462517.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Some answers here have explained how the unexpected undesired output (`'1,23,4'`) happens and some have explained how to obtain what they assume to be the expected desired output (`[1,2,3,4]`), i.e. array concatenation. However, the nature of the expected desired output is actually somewhat ambiguous because the original question simply states "I wanted to add the elements of an array into another...". That *could* mean array concatenation but it could *also* mean tuple addition (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16548584/5218951) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/497885/5218951)), i.e. adding the scalar values of elements in one array to the scalar values of the corresponding elements in the second, e.g. combining `[1,2]` and `[3,4]` to obtain `[4,6]`.

Assuming both arrays have the same arity/length, here is one simple solution:

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2];
const arr2 = [3, 4];

const add = (a1, a2) => a1.map((e, i) => e + a2[i]);

console.log(add(arr1, arr2)); // ==> [4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **ES6**, we can do something similar to what we want using the spread operator:

```
[...[1, 2], ...[3, 4]]
```

gives:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

It also works with named variables:

```
const a = [1, 2];
const b = [3, 4];
const array = [...a, ...b];
```

gives the same result.

Answer (score -1):

Another result using just a simple "+" sign will be:

```
[1,2]+','+[3,4] === [1,2,3,4]
```

So something like this should work (but!):

```
var a=[1,2];
var b=[3,4];
a=a+','+b; // [1,2,3,4]
```

... but it will convert the variable a from an Array to String! Keep it in mind.