# using array of string with map in Javascript

Tags: javascript, computer-science

I have the following JavaScript code :

```
 function dox( )
         {    
          d= [1, 2, 3] + [1,2,3]     ;

          d.map(function(value) {return parseInt(value)});
          document.writeln(d );

      }
```

and I got the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.
```

I spent a lot of time to solve this bug but I could not ,

Could somebody explain me what is the problem !?

Thanks

Comment: Many things went wrong in so little code... Try reading some JavaScript tutorials first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does \[1,2\] + \[3,4\] = "1,23,4" in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124884/why-does-1-2-3-4-1-23-4-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d= [1, 2, 3] + [1,2,3]
```

This does not concatenate arrays, you need:

```
var someVar = array1.concat(array2);
```

If you use `+` on arrays they will get coerced to strings then concatenated so you actually get a string containing `"1,2,31,2,3"`

Strings don't have a `map` function and that's why you get the error

You probably need to put `var` in front of that `d` variable so it doesn't leak into the global scope.