# Performance difference between []+[] and [].join(',')+[].join(',')

Tags: javascript

Just while fiddling through arrays i found this.

why there is significant difference between the following three statements:

```
[1,2]+[3,4];

[1,2].toString()+[3,4].toString();

[1,2].join(',')+[3,4].join(',');
```

[image]
And if `[1,2]+[1,2]` performs the same as converting to string and then joining the two strings, then shouldnt be performance of them be somewhat similar

This question is inspired from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7130218/3556874)

Comment: I'd assume because you are telling the javascript engine to convert to a string which has faster operators that a generic array that can contain any object.

Comment: In all cases it's about a microsecond or less per operation. What difference does it make? It probably varies between JavaScript platforms anyway.

Comment: By the way, I'm curious how `.join()` (without the redundant argument `','`) compares.

Comment: @abc123..that was quick :)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts..  looks like it becomes fastest of all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably has something to do with implicit and explicit coercion.

For `[1,2]+[3,4]`, the interpreter has to figure out on it's own that `string` is the desired output.

For both `[1,2].toString()+[3,4].toString();` and `[1,2].join(',')+[3,4].join(',');`, you're already telling the interpreter it's working with strings.

The difference between the last 2 lines is pretty much negligible.

In the end, even if you're doing this a million times, you're not really going to notice a difference.