# How is JavaScript Engine changing the type of Array Object to String

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```
 let arr = [1,2,3];
 let empArr =[];

 for(var i =0; i< arr.length;i++){

  console.log('First',typeof empArr);

  empArr+=arr[i];

  console.log('Second',typeof empArr)
 }
```

The above code gives this output

```
    First object
    Second string
    First string
    Second string
    First string
    Second string
```

Could anyone explain how in first iteration type was Array Object then after that it became string.How Javascript Engine works here?

Comment: I don't know why it does it but I do know that you can use `empArr.push(arr[i])` to have it stay an array

Comment: Because you don't use `+=` to push to arrays, that is a string append operation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is \[1,2\] + \[3,4\] = "1,23,4" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124884/why-is-1-2-3-4-1-23-4-in-javascript)

Comment: @BenFortune I agree we don't use += to push arrays,by mistake i did this and saw this result so wanted to know how JS engine is behaving here.

Comment: As per the link @Jeto posted, the `+` operator is not defined for arrays, Javascript will convert arrays into strings and concatenate those

Answer (score 3):

If we run `typeof empArr`, we will see `empArr` an object. No matter if we declare it as an array, internally, it is an object. Further, `typeof arr[i]` shows `arr[i]` is a number. Therefore, `empArr+=arr[i]` means we are trying to add an object and a number. Since we are trying to add two different types, it can happen with the help of coercion, implicitly. Coercion means, converting a value of one type to another. JavaScript performs implicit coercion as per the following rules:

operand + operand = result

1. If at least one operand is an object, it is converted to a primitive
   value (string, number or boolean);
2. After conversion, if at least one operand is string type, the second operand is converted to and the concatenation is executed;
3. In other case both operands converted to numbers and arithmetic addition is executed.

Note that the primitive value of an array or object is a string.

In our case, `empArr` is of type object and by rule 1, it is coerced as a string. Now by rule 2, the `arr[i]` which is a number, is coerced to a string as well and get assigned to `empArr`.

For more details:

[JavaScript addition operator in details](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascriptss-addition-operator-demystified)

[JavaScript type coercion](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839)

Answer (score 1):

It's because of auto type conversion.

The += is a not an array operator, and as the second operand is string - the 1st is converted to string.

Use empArr.push(arr[i])

Answer (score 1):

According to javascript,
`typeof []` is "`object`" ,i.e., every array is actually an object.

if you append anything to a string it will become a string
`"1"+1` will equal `"11"`