# JS Array Destructing - How is it giving this output?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Output of the code:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log([...arr + []]);
```

gives

```
​​​​​[ '1', ',', '2', ',', '3', ',', '4', ',', '5' ]​​​​​
```

I know `...arr` would return array items (like 1 2 3 4 5) and `number + []` gives string, but I really got confused on why `,` is been added to the output array.

Is it because the `...arr` in `console.log()` 
turns out to be `[..."1, 2, 3, 4, 5" + []]` in which the output is the same?

Or is the some magical explanation that I am unaware of?

Comment: because `arr + [] === "1,2,3,4,5"` (and there's no destructuring here)

Comment: @CertainPerformance what you mean is - there's no `array destructuring` here.

Comment: There's no destructuring at all (array or otherwise)

Comment: Oh, thanks for clearing that out.

Comment: *"I know `...arr`would return array items"* It does not. `...` is not an operator, it doesn't do anything. `...arr` by itself would be as invalid as `:arr` would be. `...` is part of the array literal syntax (and function definition/call syntax, and destruturing syntax) and has different meaning depending on where it is used. Just like `;` means something different inside a `for` loop header and at the end of a statement. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124907/9259778) is an explanation on `+` operator applied to arrays. So what happens is this:

1. `arr + []` gives you a string `"1,2,3,4,5"`
2. Then that string is spreaded/splitted (with the spread syntax) into an array of characters of that string.

Comment: Oh. So, basically it behaves like `console.log([...(arr + [])]);`. Thanks

Comment: @PrameshBajracharya exactly. In other words `+` operator has higher priority here.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev: `...` is not an operator. Is part of the array literal syntax, just like `,` is.

Comment: @FelixKling So it's a common misconception? Googling "spread operator" gives tons of links. But developer.mozilla.org has zero mentions of it.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. At the beginning MDN listed this syntax under operators. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508 too

Answer (score 1):

Adding on Nurbol's answer when you do

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log([...arr + []]);
```

It will turn out to a string with each element inside the array converting it to a string. Since the comma is also here so it will be an element of the string array.

When you do it like this

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log((arr + []).split())
```

It creates the single string of that array and then you create an array of a string specifying the split point.

Answer (score 0):

`array.toString()` adds `,` after each element

```
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(a.toString())
// -> '1,2,3,4,5'
console.log([...a.toString()])
// -> [ '1', ',', '2', ',', '3', ',', '4', ',', '5' ]
```

`[...aray + []]` converts array to string then adds empty string and then uses `[...resultString]` to build result