# Why adding two single element arrays giving me a string and subtracting them gives me a number?

Tags: javascript

*Edited

I recently stumbled upon an interesting as well as a peculiar problem with arrays in js.

[image]

As you can see above subtraction is giving me a number but addition gives me a string. I've also tried the same with multiplication and division and got number in both the cases.

Then I became more curious and tried with multi element arrays and here is the result

[image]

Now I really want to figure out how and why is this happening. Please help me on this.

**Edit:**  I've added more examples and below are the results

[image]

As you can see above "1"+"1" is "11" which seems fine but [] returns an empty array and [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw7TR.jpg)] returns 1 with key 0 and as we know arrays are also objects and that leads to confusion.

Comment: subtraction coerces to a number, addition, being ambiguous with concatenation, follows a more complex coercion pattern, with a pref for strings. it's all well-documented though...

Comment: When you are doing operations on array types, the `+` operator is being treated as concatenation instead of addition.

Comment: it can get worse :D example : `false-1-"1"*true+"2"-0 =-22` and a lot of other examples ^^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is \[1,2\] + \[3,4\] = "1,23,4" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124884/why-is-1-2-3-4-1-23-4-in-javascript)

Comment: @dandavis but please help me understand why [2] - [1] works and [1, 2, 3] - [4, 5, 6] not?

Comment: because that's `"2"-"1"` vs `"1,2,3"-"4,5,6"`, which doesn't work because of the commas.

Answer (score 0):

When operating on elements in an array, the `+` operator performs a concatenation, not an addition.

For example, if you look at your case in which you try to do `[1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6]`, the console treats the arrays as strings and joins the addend directly to the augend, giving a result of "1, 2, 34, 5, 6".  The `-, /, *, %` operators perform arithmetic operations, which are integer operations rather than string or array operations, and cannot be performed on arrays.  That is why that returns `NaN`.

If you're wondering why the numbers are added together as strings, it's because of type coercion.  Concatenation is a string operation, not an integer operation, so the numbers are converted to a string.

If you want to append one array to another array, you can use `.concat()`.  If you want to add each element (i.e. [0]<sub>1</sub> + [0]<sub>2</sub>, ...), you can use a `for` loop.  If you want to sum the elements in a list, use reduce with an accumulator.

---

Links: [Explanation](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839), [Type conversion docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Type_conversion)

Related tags: [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [arrays](/questions/tagged/arrays), [coercion](/questions/tagged/coercion), [concatenation](/questions/tagged/concatenation), [types](/questions/tagged/types)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript arrays are objects, and arithmetic operator does not apply for them; + however performs concatenation. to join array objects, concat()

```js
console.log("1" + "1") // = 11
console.log("1" - "1") // = 0

console.log(parseFloat("1") + parseFloat("1")) // = 2
console.log(parseFloat("1" + "1")) // = 11

console.log(eval("1") + eval("1")) // = 2
console.log(eval("1" + "1")) // = 11


var a = [1, 2, 3],
    b = [11, 22, 33, 44];
var c = a.concat(b);

console.log(c)
```