# split method and array concatenation js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, split

- to understand the split method I went over this link https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp
- but not sure why comma not adding after 3 and why empty array not showing up in the output
- is it just doing array concatenation
- i debugged but not sure
- can you guys let me know.

```or-tag-here
[123] + [] + 'foo'.split('');
"123f,o,o"
```

Comment: Why are you adding/concatenating arrays?

Comment: What you want to do? Add a comma after `123`?

Comment: @epascarello hey I am trying to learn concatenation and split operations

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124884/why-is-1-2-3-4-1-23-4-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the array is converted to string. Implicitly `join()` is called on it. So `[].join()` is `''` that's why it doesn't show up in string.

But if you use some empty elements then it will show `,`

```js
console.log([123] + [,] + 'foo'.split(''));
```

#### How to concat arrays:

There can be different ways to concat two or more arrays. The modern one is using Spread Operator.

```js
console.log([...[123], ...[],...'foo'.split('')]);
```

Comment: can you let me know in my code `when array is converted to string`

Comment: @zizi Whenever you apply `+` operator b/w two arrays. Arrays will be converted to a string   .

Comment: hey in spread operator can you let me know why its printing in next line?

Comment: @zizi It doesn't matter. If you use the normal console it will work fine. Also its an array not a string.

Comment: hey when I give comma inside an array, can you tell me why I am getting undefined :(