# Why does an empty array plus false in JS return a string?

Tags: javascript

Why does an empty array plus false return the string "false"?

```
> [] + false

> "false"
```

An empty array is false, right?

Then false + false = false? No?

Comment: empty array -> toString() -> `''` -> plus something -> string as result.

Comment: @NinaScholz This does not explain why there's a `.toString()` call in the first place.

Comment: Operator `+` casts to `string` or `number` (whatever is possible, in this order). It doesn't cast to `Boolean`.

Comment: right, it is the plus sign, which triggers the operands to a usable form.

Comment: Would this work as a suitable dupe target? [What exactly is Type Coercion in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript)

Comment: To add: `+` does an **addition** on operands when they are a combination of numbers or Boolean (true=1, false=0, null=0) (`undefined` or `NaN` will result in `NaN`). Everything else would be **concatenation** by converting it to `string`. Also `[]` empty array is not `false`.

Comment: Where you see array to string?

Comment: Do you mean this `if (typeof [] === "") { alert('equal'); }`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: because [the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-addition-operator-plus) says so.

Longer answer: When the left operand of the `+` operator is not a string or a number, the operand will be converted to either one of those depending on their "preferred" primitive type (defined in the spec). The array's "preferred" type is a string and `[].toString()` is an empty string.

Then, still according to the spec, because the left operand is a string (following the previous conversion), the right operand will be converted to a string and the result of the `+` operation will be the concatenation of both strings.

In other words, `[] + false` is equivalent to `[].toString() + false.toString()` (or `"" + "false"`) and results in the string `"false"`.

Other interesting results as a consequence of this:

```
[1,2,3] + false // "1,2,3false"
[1,[2]] + false // "1,2false"
[] + {} // "[object Object]"
```

Comment: Okay, but empty string it is false

Comment: @OPV What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

The '+' operator casts to `string` or `number` (whatever is possible).

It doesn't cast to `Boolean`, check it out for yourself:

```
const x = [] + false;
const y = false + false;
console.log(typeof(x)); // string
console.log(typeof(y)); // number
```

Comment: Operator casts to string in this case "String" + false, but empty array is not string

Comment: @OPV: Yes, but it is "castable" to a string, and in this specific case - to `''`.

Answer (score 2):

> The general rule for addition in JavaScript is simple: You can only add numbers and strings, all other values will be converted to either one of those types.

Source: https://2ality.com/2012/11/coercing-objects.html

First the `+` operator must make sure that it operates on primitives (either numbers or strings). If an operand isn't a primitive it must first convert it.

Here are the rules:

1. If the operand is a primitive then stop.
2. Otherwise call its `.valueOf()` method. If the return value is a primitive then stop.
3. Otherwise call its `.toString()` method.

In `[] + false`, `[]` isn't a primitive. Let's convert it:

```
([]).valueOf();  //=> [] (not a primitive)
([]).toString(); //=> "" (primitive)
```

We now have `"" + false` to solve.

If any operand is a string, then `+` returns the concatenation of both operands. Meaning that `false` must be converted to a string:

```
(false).toString(); //=> "false"
```

The final operation becomes `"" + "false"` which returns `"false"`.

---

#### What does `false + false` return?

Both operands are primitives and both aren't strings. So they must both be converted to numbers.

```
Number(false); //=> 0
+false;        //=> 0
```

Therefore `false + false` becomes `0 + 0` which returns `0`.

---

#### How to make `[] + false` returns `42`?

Simple:

1. Force `[]` to return `42`
2. `42 + false` will cause `false` to be coerced into a number: `0`
3. `42 + 0` returns `42`

Example:

```js
var empty_arr = [];
empty_arr.valueOf = () => 42;
console.log(empty_arr + false);
```

Or: (but that's nasty)

```js
Array.prototype.valueOf = () => 42;

console.log([] + false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's because JS is trying to concat an array and then adds the string. Take a look on this:

```
[1] + true  // "1true"
[2] + 5  // "25"
[2, 3, 4] + 5  // "2,3,45"
```

Similar to:

```
"".concat([3, 2, 1]);  // "3,2,1"
```

More info: [Why is [1,2] + [3,4] = "1,23,4" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124884/why-is-1-2-3-4-1-23-4-in-javascript)

Comment: Why if [1] is not string, why it converts and concatenates with string?

Comment: Because of using `+` with array.

Comment: Strings and arrays are similar for JS so it tries to convert one to another.