# push and pop not adding arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, shift

I know that `shift` and `unshift` is used to remove or add elements at the beginning of an array.Below is the simple Javascript Code.

```
var arx = ["Plumber",12,14,15,[18,"Try"]];
console.log("The array is :- ",arx);
arx.shift();    // SHIFT removes element from beginning
console.log("The array after shift operation is :- "+arx);
arx.unshift(11,"Try",["ABC",34,"GTH"],999);  ////////////   LINE 1
console.log("The array array unshift operation is :- "+arx);
```

Below is the output

[image]

I am not able to understand why after shift opeartion , my entire array is being displayed  in series like that without any square bracket and all. Even the last element which is itself an array `[18,'Try']` has been broken into two different elements. Even the unshift opeartion is adding every element one by one and is not adding array `["ABC",34,"GTH"]` from line 1 in the form of array.Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: It's due to how `.toString` works. You're using `+` to concatenate the array to a string. Instead try listing the array as a separate argument in console.log? `console.log("The array array unshift operation is :- ", arx)`

Comment: It worked thanks a lot. Btw, can you tell me some good sources to learn javascript.I am newbiee in it.

Comment: https://justjavascript.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you notice, in your console.logs you are adding "+" sign before arx. Try replacing it with a comma

```js
var arx = ["Plumber",12,14,15,[18,"Try"]];
console.log("The array is :- ",arx);
arx.shift();    // SHIFT removes element from beginning
console.log("The array after shift operation is :- ",arx);
arx.unshift(11,"Try",["ABC",34,"GTH"],999);  ////////////   LINE 1
console.log("The array array unshift operation is :- ",arx);
```

Comment: Why does + sign makes it like that ??

Comment: With the `+` operator where you were using it, you simply were concatenating an array with a string, that's why javascript transformed your array into a string. Try `console.log(+arx)`, the result will be NaN.
Another syntax for the console.logs which resulted in the way you didn't want would be : ``console.log(`The array after shift operation is :- ${arx}`)`` For concatenation, check out **string interpolation** (in javascript)

Comment: for a better understanding of the `+` operator, check out the most upvoted comment there [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124884/why-is-1-2-3-4-1-23-4-in-javascript]