# Why does ",,," == Array(4) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Boot up your interpreter/console and try the comparison:

```
> ",,," == Array(4)
True
```

Why?  At first I thought maybe since you could think of ",,," as an array of four characters with a '\0' terminating slice, that might be why, but

```
> "..." == Array(4)
```

Returns "False".  So... why?  I know it's some idiosyncratic bit of [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) in JavaScript, but I am just curious what underlines this behavior.  I gleaned this from Zed Shaw's excellent [presentation here, btw](http://vimeo.com/43380467).

Comment: Few languages apart from C use zero-termination in a way visible to the programmer.

Comment: If I may ask, what lead to this discovery?

Comment: @SomeKittens Zed Shaw mentions this explicitly in the video I linked to in my question (as a criticism of Javascript).  Cheers!

Comment: @SomeKittens This is also mentioned in the (pretty well known) "wat" talk, showing some quirks in Ruby and JavaScript https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: Type coercion is a hell of a feature: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724255/why-does-2-2-in-javascript

Comment: another f**ed example from js, thanks:)!

Comment: This is one of many good reasons to always use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: This works out to be true in this case, but you have to be careful. The only reason this ends up using String comparison is because the valueOf() method for arrays doesn't return a primitive type. ToPrimitive doesn't pass a type hint to \[\[DefaultValue\]\], so \[\[DefaultValue\]\] defaults to the Number (unless you're calling it on a Date).

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Because the right hand operand is converted to a string  and the string representation of `Array(4)` is `,,,`:

```
> Array(4).toString()
  ",,,"
```

If you use the array constructor function and pass a number, it sets the length of the array to that number. So you can say you have four empty indexes (same as `[,,,]`) and the default string representation of arrays is a comma-separated list of its elements:

```
> ['a','b','c'].toString()
  "a,b,c"
```

---

How the comparison works is described in section [11.9.3 of the specification](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3). There you will see (`x == y`):

> 8. If Type(*x*) is either String or Number and Type(*y*) is Object,
>      return the result of the comparison *x* == [ToPrimitive](http://es5.github.com/#x9.1)(*y*).

*<sub>(arrays are objects in JavaScript)</sub>*

and if you follow the `ToPrimitive` method you will eventually find that it it calls `toString`.

Comment: Which, in turn, is because arrays stringify as if they were using `Array.join(",")`.

Comment: You have to be bloody patient to program in javascript

Answer (score 32):

Try using `===`.  When using `==` in JavaScript, it will attempt to cast the variables, thus leading to issues like this one.  The console is casting `Array(4)` to the string representation (i.e., `Array(4).toString`), which is `",,,"`.  The reason the commas are there is that the `.toString()` function adds them to separate items in an array.

See the snippet below:

```js
document.write( Array(4).toString() );
```

Answer (score 31):

Internally, it’s going:

```
",,," == Array(4).toString()
```

Answer (score 18):

This is because `Array(4)` initialises an array of 4 empty values, an `==` implicitly converts, so:

```
 ",,," == Array(4)

 ",,," == Array(4).toString()

 ",,," == ["", "", "", ""] // note 3 commas for 4 values

 ",,," == ["", "", "", ""].toString()
```

Are all similar.

`==` does implicit type conversions before comparing the values, which can result in unpredictable results. Use `===` to check the type and the value.

Answer (score 5):

Comparing an Array to a string coerces the Array to a string before doing the comparison. Coercing an empty 4-element Array to a string yields that exact string.

Answer (score 4):

I first thought it was something with the "prototype"... But after a little investigation, I reached a sad conclusion...

Apparently it is an internal and more obscure JavaScript thing with not much logic...

Just try

```
Array(4)==Array(4)
```

and no coercion on types also...

```
Array(4)===Array(4)
```

and you'll get FALSE.

You know that `null==null`, `null===null` and even `undefined==undefined` and `undefined===undefined` returns TRUE... so... it's a bit obscure...

`Array(4)==[,,,]` should also be true.

Comment: ZEE, Array(4)==[,,,] wont be true. If we compare object with primitive, then the object will be converted into primitive. Thats the reason it calls toString().

Comment: array(x) should be the address of the constructor... anyway, in a system (dont bother what kind of system), <identity_X>===<identity_X> sould always be true!