# Why does ",,," == new Array(4)

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does “,,,” == Array(4) in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905350/why-does-array4-in-javascript)

In JavaScript why does

```
",,," == new Array(4)
```

It returns true in Chrome Developer Tools, and nodejs console.

Comment: Kind of ironic that `[,,,] != new Array(4)`

Comment: a `==` comparisation will compare only values. So both sides are type casted to string. Try `===` comparisation

Answer (score 4):

```
console.log(new Array(4).toString()); // ",,,"
```

casted to **string** with above value making both equal.

```
",,," == ",,," // true
```

JS sees that on left hand is a string and on right hand side an array which is not good for comparison, it casts array to string and then does the comparison.

Notice that:

```
log(",,," === new Array(4));
```

would result in `false` since `===` checks not only for `value` but also `type` and types are different of course.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `new Array(4)` is being implicitly cast to a string, which will equal `",,,"` (four empty elements, comma separated).

Answer (score 2):

Because `Array(4).toString()` returns `",,,"` - 4 empty elements, so only the commas between them

Answer (score 1):

An array in String form produces a comma separated list of the elements, ie `1,2,3,4`. If there are no elements in the Array, it will show up as `,,,`.

`(new Array(4)).toString()` produces `,,,`.

Note that `new Array(4) === ",,,"` returns false.